# List all currently open file handles?

Tags: python, linux, filehandle

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [check what files are open in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2023608/check-what-files-are-open-in-python)

Hello,

Is it possible to obtain a list of all currently open file handles, I presume that they are stored somewhere in the environment.

I am interested in theis function as I would like to safely handle any files that are open when a fatal error is raised, i.e. close file handles and replace potentially corrupted files with the original files.

I have the handling working but without knowing what file handles are open, I am unable to implement this idea.

As an aside, when a file handle is initialised, can this be inherited by another imported method?

Thank you

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2023608/check-what-files-are-open-in-python

Comment: which o/s?  And it might help to add that as a tag too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *nice* way of doing this would be to modify your code to keep track of when it opens a file:

```
def log_open( *args, **kwargs ):
    print( "Opening a file..." )
    print( *args, **kwargs )
    return open( *args, **kwargs )
```

Then, use `log_open` instead of `open` to open files. You could even do something more hacky, like modifying the `File` class to log itself. That's covered in the linked question above.

There's probably a *disgusting, filthy hack* involving the garbage collector or looking in `__dict__` or something, but you don't want to do that unless you *absolutely really truly seriously **must***.

Answer (score 6):

lsof, /proc/pid/fd/

Comment: I used `lsof -p <pid_of_python_process>` as found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12468629/lsof-should-give-all-open-files-for-a-set-of-pids#12468794

Answer (score 0):

If you're using python 2.5+ you can use the `with` keyword (though 2.5 needs `from **future** import with_statement)

```
with open('filename.txt', 'r') as f:
    #do stuff here
    pass
#here f has been closed and disposed properly - even with raised exceptions
```

I don't know what kind of catastrophic failure needs to bork the `with` statement, but I assume it's a really bad one. On WinXP, my quick unscientific test:

```
import time
with open('test.txt', 'w') as f:
   f.write('testing\n')
   while True:
       time.sleep(1)
```

and then killing the process with Windows Task Manager still wrote the data to file.