# lsof should give all open files for a set of pids

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, freebsd, lsof

I have 30 instances of a process running on a server and want to log open files for each process for analysis.

I ran the following command:

```
* ps auwwx | grep PROG_NAME | awk '{print $2}' | xargs lsof -p | less
```

It complaints that, *"lsof: status error on : No such file or directory"*

However, if I run `lsof -p < pid >` it gives me the list of open files for that process . How can I get a list of all open files for all 30 instances of the process on a FreeBSD machine.

Moreover, I do not want the shared libraries to be listed. If I do `-d "^txt"` it isn't showing some other db files which I want to be shown. Is there any other way to grep out the .so files?

Comment: FYI for the Internet passer-by: I wanted to solve a similar problem--counting the number of open files per process, specifically Java. I did it like this: `pgrep java | xargs -I {} bash -c 'printf {}; lsof -p {} | wc -l'`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The `lsof -p` option takes a comma-separated list of PIDs.  The way you're using `xargs` will pass the pids as separate arguments leading some to be interpreted as filenames.

Try `lsof -p $(your grep | tr '\012' ,)`  That's going to have a trailing comma, I'm not sure if `lsof` will care but you could `sed` it off if necessary.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `xargs -L1 lsof -p` to run `lsof` once per pid.

Even better: use `lsof -c` to list all open files from commands matching a specific pattern:

```
lsof -c bas # list all processes with commands starting with 'bas'
lsof -c '/ash$/x' # list all commands ending with 'ash' (regexp syntax)
```