# xargs not working with lsof

Tags: macos, xargs, lsof

When I run `pgrep vim | xargs echo`, it prints `93868 91234`.

When I run `lsof -p 91234`, it prints:

```
COMMAND   PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE  SIZE/OFF    NODE NAME
vim     91234 rose  cwd    DIR    1,2      1326 1186863 /Users/rose/spotapi/spotapi/models
vim     91234 rose  txt    REG    1,2   1629296   12231 /usr/bin/vim
vim     91234 rose  txt    REG    1,2   2704416  294199 /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Python
```

Why then does

```
pgrep vim | xargs lsof -p
```

print

```
lsof: status error on 91234: No such file or directory
```

I'm running on Mac OS.

Comment: cannot replicate this error on a linux, maybe it's [this issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12468629/lsof-should-give-all-open-files-for-a-set-of-pids)? or does [lsof -c](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12468802/2399627) help?

Answer (score 5):

I see this on my Slackware installation.  If you run `lsof -p 93868 91234` you will see the problem.  The reason is that `xargs` shoves all the arguments onto one command line if it can.  You can use the `-n` option to specify the maximum number of arguments.

```
pgrep vim | xargs -n1 lsof -p
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can supply multiple PIDs by replacing spaces with commas:

```
lsof -p `pgrep vim | xargs echo | sed -re 's/ /,/g'`
```

In the example above, I use xargs to pass all pids to echo as a way of getting them into a single line, and then replace spaces with commas. The executed command against lsof is:

```
lsof -p 1111,2222
```

An easier way of doing this (if you know the process name, e.g. vim) and don't need pgrep:

```
lsof -p `pidof vim | sed -re 's/ /,/g'`
```

Not 100% sure of compatibility and availability of this in osx, this was a Fedora / Ubuntu.