# How can I see which files python is reading or editing, with Python's PID?

Tags: python, file, jupyter, interpreter, pid

How to see which files Python is reading or editing, knowing only its PID?
I did some researches but found nothing.
(on a Jupyter web server running Ubuntu)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [check what files are open in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2023608/check-what-files-are-open-in-python)

Comment: Also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3370694/499581

Answer (score 1):

The [`lsof`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/lsof.8.html) command shows what files a process has open.

```
lsof -p 123
```

will show the files currently opened by PID 123.