# Too many open files in python

Tags: python, file-descriptor

I wrote kind of a test suite which is heavily file intensive. After some time (2h) I get an `IOError: [Errno 24] Too many open files: '/tmp/tmpxsqYPm'`. I double checked all file handles whether I close them again. But the error still exists.

I tried to figure out the number of allowed file descriptors using `resource.RLIMIT_NOFILE` and the number of currently opened file desciptors:

```
def get_open_fds():

    fds = []
    for fd in range(3,resource.RLIMIT_NOFILE):
            try:
                    flags = fcntl.fcntl(fd, fcntl.F_GETFD)
            except IOError:
                    continue

            fds.append(fd)

    return fds
```

So if I run the following test:

```
print get_open_fds()
for i in range(0,100):
    f = open("/tmp/test_%i" % i, "w")
    f.write("test")
    print get_open_fds()
```

I get this output:

```
[]
/tmp/test_0
[3]
/tmp/test_1
[4]
/tmp/test_2
[3]
/tmp/test_3
[4]
/tmp/test_4
[3]
/tmp/test_5
[4] ...
```

That's strange, I expected an increasing number of opened file descriptors. Is my script correct?

I'm using python's logger and subprocess. Could that be the reason for my fd leak?

Thanks,
Daniel

Comment: please cat /proc/sys/fs/file-max and cat /proc/sys/fs/file-nr

Comment: You should use `resource.getrlimit(resource.RLIMIT_NOFILE)`. `resource.RLIMIT_NOFILE` is just a constanct to access the information.

Comment: Would subprocess.Popen cause similar issues?

Comment: Seems related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2023608/check-what-files-are-open-in-python

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your test script overwrites `f` each iteration, which means that the file will get closed each time. Both logging to files and `subprocess` with pipes use up descriptors, which can lead to exhaustion.

Comment: my fault, thanks for the hint! It seems that get_open_fds() does its job. But resource.RLIMIT_NOFILE = 7 and my the error occurs after I opened 1024 files. Anyways, I know how to debug my scripts - thanks so far!!!

Comment: @Informant can you post the fix too? I have the same problem but don't know how to fix it. Thanx.

Answer (score 14):

The corrected code is:

```
import resource
import fcntl
import os

def get_open_fds():
    fds = []
    soft, hard = resource.getrlimit(resource.RLIMIT_NOFILE)
    for fd in range(0, soft):
        try:
            flags = fcntl.fcntl(fd, fcntl.F_GETFD)
        except IOError:
            continue
        fds.append(fd)
    return fds

def get_file_names_from_file_number(fds):
    names = []
    for fd in fds:
        names.append(os.readlink('/proc/self/fd/%d' % fd))
    return names

fds = get_open_fds()
print get_file_names_from_file_number(fds)
```

Comment: It would be more helpful to say what is wrong with the original. Not everyone wants to play 'spot the difference'.

Answer (score 10):

resource.RLIMIT_NOFILE is indeed 7, but that's an index into resource.getrlimit(), not the limit itself... resource.getrlimit(resource.RLIMIT_NOFILE) is what you want your top range() to be