# I'm trying to build a big video from ~400 videos, however I'm facing issues with "Too many files open"

Tags: python, batch-processing, moviepy

I'm trying to build a big video from ~400 videos, however I'm facing issues with "Too many files open". I've read the documentation (and saw this [post](https://github.com/Zulko/moviepy/issues/57)).

However I'm still getting the same error: `OSError: [Errno 24] Too many open files`

I've investigated and don't know what else to do if I'm already deleting each opened movie with the method `close_files`.

The code:

```
from moviepy.editor import *
import json
import os
import urllib
import shutil
import re
import api.constants
import traceback
from api.constants import *
import datetime
import string


def close_files(files):
    for file in files:
        try:
            if not (isinstance(file,ImageClip) or isinstance(file,TextClip)):
                del file.reader
            del file
        except Exception,e:
            print "Exception: "+str(e)

def max_text(title,author):
    return title
    #if len(title) > 120:
    #    return title[0:(120- len(author))]+"..."
    #else:
    #    return title

def clean(text):
    return ''.join(filter(lambda x: x in string.printable, text))

def compile_videos(fileName,serverjson,post_to):
    try:
        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        print "Starting at: "+str(now)

        #Video's dimensions
        w = 1440
        h = 1440
        videoDimension = w,h

        #Video offset
        videoOffset = 580
        titleOffset = 0

        #Movie dimensions
        w2 = 2560
        h2 = 1440
        movieDimensions = w2,h2

        #Title dimensions
        w3 = 540
        h3 = 1440
        titleDimensions = w3,h3

        #Left Holder Dimension
        holderDimensions = 500,500
        holderPosition = 50,450


        #Holder
        left_holder = ImageClip("assets/everyday_icon.png").set_position(holderPosition)
        if post_to=="7min":
            left_holder = ImageClip("assets/7min_icon.png").set_position(holderPosition)
        elif post_to=="7x7":
            left_holder = ImageClip("assets/7x7_icon.png").set_position(holderPosition)

        #Temporal directory
        directory = 'tmp'
        if os.path.exists(directory):
          shutil.rmtree(directory)
        if not os.path.exists(directory):
          os.makedirs(directory)

        #Read Videos/Files

        data = serverjson

        videos_and_subtitles = []
        #We add the holder so that there's always a background
        videos_and_subtitles.append(left_holder)

        currentDuration = 0
        videoId = ""
        preprocessedVideos = []
        counter = 0
        videoNumber = 0
        print "Total videos: "+str(len(data["videos"]))
        for videoObject in data["videos"]:
            counter+=1
            #Download video and thumbnail
            downloader=urllib.URLopener()
            videoId = videoObject[API_VIDEO_ID]
            videoPath = directory+"/"+str(videoObject[API_VIDEO_ID])+'_video.mp4'
            thumbPath = directory+"/"+str(videoObject[API_VIDEO_ID])+'_thumb.jpg'
            try:
                downloader.retrieve(str(videoObject[API_VIDEO_URL]),videoPath)
                downloader.retrieve(str(videoObject[API_THUMB_URL]),thumbPath)
            except Exception,e:
                print "Exception: "+str(e)
                print "Video ID: "+str(videoId)
                traceback.print_exc()
                continue
            #Create new video and update video duration's offset
            newVideo = VideoFileClip(videoPath).resize(height=w,width=h).set_position((videoOffset,titleOffset)).set_start(currentDuration)
            #Append new video to videos

            videos_and_subtitles.append(newVideo)
            #Append subtitle to Subtitles
            videoName = clean(videoObject[API_NAME])
            videoAuthor = clean(videoObject[API_AUTHOR])
            newSubtitleText = clean(max_text(videoName,videoAuthor)+" \n\n"+videoObject[API_AUTHOR])
            newSubtitle = ( TextClip(newSubtitleText,fontsize=70,color='white',font='Helvetica-Narrow',align='center',method='caption',size=titleDimensions).set_start(currentDuration).set_position((videoOffset+w,0)).set_duration(newVideo.duration) )
            videos_and_subtitles.append(newSubtitle)
            currentDuration+=newVideo.duration

            #Preprocess videos
            if counter%50==0 or len(data["videos"])==(counter):
                currentFilename=directory+"/"+str(videoNumber)+fileName
                result = CompositeVideoClip(videos_and_subtitles,size=movieDimensions,bg_color=(0,164,119)).set_duration(currentDuration).write_videofile(filename=currentFilename,preset='ultrafast',fps=24)
                preprocessedVideos.append(VideoFileClip(currentFilename))
                close_files(videos_and_subtitles)
                videos_and_subtitles = []
                currentDuration = 0
                videoNumber+=1
                if (videoObject==data["videos"][-1]):
                    break
            print "Next video"

        print "Compiling video"
        result = concatenate_videoclips(preprocessedVideos).write_videofile(filename=directory+"/"+fileName,preset='ultrafast')
        #result = CompositeVideoClip(videos_and_subtitles,size=movieDimensions,bg_color=(0,164,119)).set_duration(currentDuration).write_videofile(filename=directory+"/"+fileName,preset='ultrafast')
        print "Video Compiled"
        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        print "Finished at: "+str(now)
        return fileName
    except Exception,e:
        print "Exception: "+str(e)
        print "Video ID: "+str(videoId)
        traceback.print_exc()
        return None
```

I'm processing the files in batches of 50 because it takes longer if I do it in smaller batches. The problem isn't having 50 files open at once. The problem happens after the first or second batch (~100-150 files processed), this points to the files not being closed (otherwise the first batch wouldn't have been processed correctly). This means the same happens if I do it in batches of 10, it's just that the files are not being closed correctly

Other posts like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4386482/too-many-open-files-in-python), as you can see the answer:

> Your test script overwrites f each iteration, which means that the file will get closed each time. Both logging to files and subprocess with pipes use up descriptors, which can lead to exhaustion.

Doesn't quite apply, as I'm overwriting the instance every 50 iterations, however I'm still having the problem.

Also, I can't call "close" on a VideoFileClip.

Comment: *I'm already deleting each opened movie with the method close_files.* also that is **not** [how you delete a file in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6996603/how-do-i-delete-a-file-or-folder-in-python) what you are doing is either [`del` a local variable or something from a `list` or `dict`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6146963/when-is-del-useful-in-python)

Comment: I'm not trying to delete a file (each iteration does not create a file as you can see, it only instantiates a new VideoClip, which is certainly not the same). That is why I referenced the first link. Also, the "possible duplicate" is already addressed as you can see in my last paragraph. Please read the code, I'm not trying to delete a file, just "close" the reference to the VideoClip I created

Comment: *i'm already deleting each opened movie with the method close_files.*, then what do you think you are doing with the `del` keyword. The solution is **SIMPLE** close the files after you open them just like the duplicate says, or any of the other exact duplicates that say the same thing. that mysterious method is called `.close()`

Comment: Deleting the file() object and relying of garbage collection to close it *can* work in some cases in CPython, but it's not officially supported, and your code isn't doing that. Your line `del file` is just deleting the local variable you declare a few lines above, which won't affect anything. Calling `close()` explicitly on each file object should work better.

Comment: This is a bit tricky because you're not handling the files object directly, like in the linked questions. It seems like they're a couple of layers removed. It would be easier to help (and less likely to be downvoted) if you could come up with a reduced example -- the code you've provided above includes a bunch of logic irrelevant to the specific problem, and we can't run the code ourselves because it imports a local module (`api`). (FWIW, when I'm asking a question on Stack Overflow I usually spend quite a bit of time preparing an example that will be easy for others to understand and debug.)

Comment: You're right Jeremy, I'll re-edit my code so it's easier to read, thanks.

Comment: FYI, in other cases (not this one, since in this case, the open files are hidden in other packages and messing with their implementation is poor form), you can often work around open file limits by using `mmap` to map the files into memory; you open the file only long enough to get a file descriptor and `mmap` it, then close the file descriptor. The only limitation on `mmap` is contiguous virtual address space, they don't count against the open file limit, and on 64 bit machines, contiguous virtual address space is nearly infinite.

Comment: I can't call close() on VideoFileClip.