# Python; popen do not pass std*

Tags: python, process

I have a chain of three processes: Process A calls B to spawn C, then B dies. We can call B a "bridge" between two systems A and C.

I want to make sure that C DOES NOT inherit any file descriptors that A opens in order to prevent zombying, which I am currently observing (sometimes A calls B to kill C, and after this, I am seeing defunct C processes hanging around, but I don't know what the code in A looks like).

To make sure this issue isn't due to stdin/out/err being passed down, 
I am currently doing the following in *B*

```
def _close_fds(): #workaround carstens bug
    for fd in [0, 1, 2]:
        try:
            os.close(fd)
        except Exception:
            logger.info("File descriptor was not open")

...
_close_fds() #make sure there are no open file descriptors for the chile to enherit
pid = subprocess.Popen([_ROOT_PATH  + "something.py"]).pid
...
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: You're only closing stdin, stdout, and stderr. If any other file descriptors were open, they'll remain open but you're not finding them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are starting process C from B, and you don't want it to inherit any file handles, use the following arguments in `subprocess.Popen`;

1. `close_fds=True`
2. Set `stdin`, `stdout` and `stderr` to `subprocess.PIPE` or `subprocess.DEVNULL`.

The first closes all file handles except *stdin*, *stdout* and *stderr*. The arguments listed under (2) take care of those.

Answer (score 1):

The `os` module provides a nice function, [`os.closerange()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.closerange), that will do this for you in one call:

```
os.closerange(0, 3)
```

If you're hunting after phantom open files, I would go a little higher just in case:

```
os.closerange(0, 10)
```

To find out what you actually need to close, you can check `/proc/self/fd` for a list of the file descriptors that your process has open (if your OS supports it), and/or use the `open_files()` method from [psutil](https://pythonhosted.org/psutil/#psutil.Process.open_files). See the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2023608/699305) for even more ideas.