# getting OSError: too many open files when running longish test suite on code that uses multiprocessing

Tags: python, file-io, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing, contextmanager

Running python 2.7, dev environment is OS X but production is linux.

I've got some code I'm trying to speed up with multiprocessing, and I got it working fine and observed the desired theoretical speedups. I then went to run the test suite on it, and after a few tests, started getting the above OSError on all subsequent tests. If I run the tests from the point where I start getting the error, some number of them pass and then I get that error again. Which is fairly logical, just a sanity check.

To try to figure out what was going wrong, I replaced `__builtin__`'s `open` and `close` calls with ones that print (following advice in https://stackoverflow.com/a/2023709/3543200)

```
import __builtin__
import traceback
import sys
openfiles = set()
oldfile = __builtin__.file
class newfile(oldfile):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        self.x = args[0]
        print "### OPENING %s ###" % str(self.x)
        traceback.print_stack(limit=20)
        print
        sys.stdout.flush()
        oldfile.__init__(self, *args)
        openfiles.add(self)
    def close(self):
        print "### CLOSING %s ###" % str(self.x)
        oldfile.close(self)
        openfiles.remove(self)
oldopen = __builtin__.open
def newopen(*args):
    return newfile(*args)
__builtin__.file = newfile
__builtin__.open = newopen
```

and what did I see but hundreds and hundreds of lines of `### OPENING /dev/null ###`.

When I do the same thing for the code that accomplishes the same task but without the multiprocessing, I get no such file connections, so it stands to reason that the multiprocessing is at fault here. This is supported by the `traceback` call, which suggests that the culprit is here:

```
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 250, in _bootstrap
    sys.stdin = open(os.devnull)
```

posting the code of the `multiprocessing::process.py::_bootstrap` function here, just in case it's helpful:

```
def _bootstrap(self):
    from . import util
    global _current_process

    try:
        self._children = set()
        self._counter = itertools.count(1)
        try:
            sys.stdin.close()
            sys.stdin = open(os.devnull)
        except (OSError, ValueError):
            pass
        _current_process = self
        util._finalizer_registry.clear()
        util._run_after_forkers()
        util.info('child process calling self.run()')
        try:
            self.run()
            exitcode = 0
        finally:
            util._exit_function()
    except SystemExit, e:
        if not e.args:
            exitcode = 1
        elif isinstance(e.args[0], int):
            exitcode = e.args[0]
        else:
            sys.stderr.write(str(e.args[0]) + '\n')
            sys.stderr.flush()
            exitcode = 1
    except:
        exitcode = 1
        import traceback
        sys.stderr.write('Process %s:\n' % self.name)
        sys.stderr.flush()
        traceback.print_exc()

    util.info('process exiting with exitcode %d' % exitcode)
    return exitcode
```

And, for what it's worth, I'm invoking multiprocessing with code that looks like this:

```
num_cpus = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=num_cpus)
num_per_job = len(input_data) / num_cpus + 1
chunks = [input_data[num_per_job*i:num_per_job*(i+1)] for i in range(num_cpus)]
# TODO: ^^^ make this a list of generators
data = pool.map(get_output_from_input, chunks)
return itertools.chain.from_iterable(data)
```

So, question: is this a bug in `multiprocessing`, or am I doing something terribly wrong? I would really welcome the excuse to spend the next week digging through the `multiprocessing` code and figuring out how it works, but I would have trouble convincing the higher-ups that this is a valid use of my time. Appreciate anyone with experience helping out!

Comment: You don't close the pool so its child processes are not killed. If your test suite keeps calling that same code in a single process, you'll run out of resources.

Comment: Yep, just found the pool.close() function. Thanks! If you want to make a separate post I'll accept it as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to close the pools to terminate the child processes and free the pipes used to communicate with them. Do it with `contextlib.closing` so that you don't have to worry about exceptions skipping the close. `closing` will close the pool at the end of the `with` block, including when it is exited with an exception. So, you never need to call close yourself.

Also, `Pool.map` chunks its requests so you don't have to do it yourself. I removed that bit of code but the `get_output_from_input` signature may not be right (it will be called once per input item, not once with a list of input items) so you may need to do some fixups.

```
import contextlib
num_cpus = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
with contextlib.closing(multiprocessing.Pool(processes=num_cpus)) as pool:
    data = pool.map(get_output_from_input, input_data)
    return itertools.chain.from_iterable(data)
```