# python. How to get active (opened) resources (files, etc)

Tags: python

Just for curiosity...

In PHP we can get all opened in current process resources by using [`get_resources()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-resources.php)

That was really helpful in one of my tasks when one of third-party libraries didn't close opened file properly and I used `get_resources()` to close file stream to be able delete file before process ends.

So, the question is:

Is here any way in python to get and close opened somewhere inside process resources (or streams) without knowing object or method where it was opened?

Comment: To note: *resources* in PHP are a very specific thing and their own type, which is not really the case for Python. You're probably rather looking for UNIX-y tools to find all open ports/files/sockets.

Comment: Would this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2023608/check-what-files-are-open-in-python