# Inserting pyodbc.Binary data (BLOB) into SQL Server image column

Tags: python, sql-server-2008, pyodbc

I am trying to insert binary data into a column of `image` datatype in a SQL Server database. I know `varbinary(max)` is the preferred data type, but I don't have rights to alter the schema.

Anyhow, I am reading the contents of a file and wrapping it in pyodbc.Binary() as below:

```
f = open('Test.ics', 'rb')
ablob = f.read().encode('hex')
ablob = pyodbc.Binary(ablob)
```

When I `print repr(ablob)` I see the correct value `bytearray(b'424547494e3a5 . . .` (ellipsis added).

However, after inserting

```
insertSQL = """insert into documents(name, documentType, document, customerNumber) values(?,?,?,?)"""
cur.execute(insertSQL, 'test200.ics', 'text/calendar', pyodbc.Binary(ablob), 1717)
```

The value of the document column is `0x343234353 . . .` which appears as if the hexadecimal data was converted to ASCII character codes.

I thought wrapping the value in pyodbc.Binary() would take care of this? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I am using Python 2.7 and SQL Server 2008 R2 (10.50).

**Edit**:

beargle kindly pointed out that I was needlessly calling encode('hex'), which was leading to my issue. I believe this must have been coercing the data into a string (although a fuller explanation would be helpful).

Working code:

```
ablob = pyodbc.Binary(f.read())
cur.execute(insertSQL, 'test200.ics', 'text/calendar', ablob, 1717)
```

Comment: I am using the `SQL Server Native Client 10.0` driver and have also tested using the `SQL Server` driver with the same result.

Comment: Why do you need to hex encode the contents before wrapping with `pyodbc.Binary`?

Comment: Good point, I don't need to, and removing leads to the expected result. Thanks!

Comment: Good to hear. I did get this working with the hex encode, you just have to decode select results.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First make sure you use [`with open(..)`](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects) to read the file ([another example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373660/file-open-is-this-bad-python-style#1373713)). This automatically closes file objects when they are exhausted *or* an exception is raised.

```
# common vars
connection = pyodbc.connect(...)
filename = 'Test.ics'
insert = 'insert into documents (name, documentType, document, customerNumber)'

# without hex encode
with open(filename, 'rb'):
    bindata = f.read()

# with hex encode
with open(filename, 'rb'):
    hexdata = f.read().encode('hex')

# build parameters
binparams = ('test200.ics', 'text/calendar', pyodbc.Binary(bindata), 1717)
hexparams = ('test200.ics', 'text/calendar', pyodbc.Binary(hexdata), 1717)

# insert binary
connection.cursor().execute(insert, binparams)
connection.commit()

# insert hex
connection.cursor().execute(insert, hexparams)
connection.commit()

# print documents
rows = connection.cursor().execute('select * from documents').fetchall()
for row in rows:
    try:
        # this will decode hex data we inserted
        print str(row.document).decode('hex')
    # attempting to hex decode binary data throws TypeError
    except TypeError:
        print str(row.document)
```

I'm guessing you are getting the `0x343234353...` data by looking at results in Management Studio:

[image: SQL Server Management Studio results]

This doesn't mean the data is stored this way, it's just the way Management Studio represents `image`, `text`, `ntext`, `varbinary`, etc. datatypes in the result pane.

Comment: In my situation, there is another application that reads the data from this table, so I don't have control over the decoding of the binary data. With the value in row 2, this other application ends up downloading a corrupted file.