# Error Inserting data into MS SQL Server Using Python pyodbc[Error 42000]

Tags: python, sql

```
fo = open("C:\Program Files\NPKI\yessign\User\SignCert.der","rb")
sssd = fo.read()
std = "SignCert.der"
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM NPKIInf WHERE nSeqNum=5")

cursor.execute("insert into NPKIInf(nSeqNum, nFileName, nBinary) values ('7', '" + std + "', '" + sssd +"')")
cnxn.commit()
```

Above is the code and the error msg is down below:

```
C:\Python27>python import.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "import.py", line 12, in <module>
    cursor.execute("insert into NPKIInf(nSeqNum,nFileName,nBinary) values('7', '" + std + "', '" + sssd +"')")
pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][
SQL Server]\xb9\xae\xc0\xda\xbf\xad '0???\x8d\xa0\x03\x02\x01\x02\x02\x04\x14\xe
0\xd2?\r\x06\t*\x86H\x86\xf7\r\x01\x01\x0b\x05'\xc0\xc7 \xb5\xfb\xbf\xc8\xc7\xa5
\xb0\xa1 \xc2\xa6\xc0\xcc \xb8\xc2\xc1\xf6 \xbe\xca\xbd\xc0\xb4\xcf\xb4\xd9. (10
5) (SQLExecDirectW); [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]'0??
?\x8d\xa0\x03\x02\x01\x02\x02\x04\x14\xe0\xd2?\r\x06\t*\x86H\x86\xf7\r\x01\x01\x
0b\x05' \xb1\xd9\xc3\xb3\xc0\xc7 \xb1\xb8\xb9\xae\xc0\xcc \xc0\xdf\xb8\xf8\xb5\x
c7\xbe\xfa\xbd\xc0\xb4\xcf\xb4\xd9. (102)")
```

Connection to DB is Fine, I also tried just inserting hard data like

```
cursor.execute("insert into NPKIInf(nSeqNum,nFileName,nBinary) values('7','test','test'")
```

Still doesn't work.

this is the information of DB Table:

```
 CREATE TABLE [dbo].[NPKIInf](
           [nSeqNum] [smallint] NOT NULL,
           [nFileName] [nchar](50) NULL,
           [nBinary] [varbinary](max) NULL,
           [nHspName] [nchar](50) NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_NPKIInf] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
(
           [nSeqNum] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF,
ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it looks like you aren't converting to the correct datatypes, when I ran the following on SQL Server:

```
insert into NPKIInf(nSeqNum,nFileName,nBinary) values('8','test', 'test')
```

it failed, when I ran:

```
insert into NPKIInf(nSeqNum,nFileName,nBinary) values('8','test', cast('test' as varbinary))
```

as far as you're actual query goes, take a looke at: [Inserting pyodbc.Binary data (BLOB) into SQL Server image column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11836924/inserting-pyodbc-binary-data-blob-into-sql-server-image-column)

and it should answer your question

Answer (score 0):

The error messages says your (single) quotation marks do not pair.

> [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]문자열
>   '0???뜝詵?  *낷놑 '의 따옴표가 짝이 맞지 않습니다. (105) (SQLExecDirectW);
>   [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]'0???뜝詵?
>    *낷놑 ' 근처의 구문이 잘못되었습니다. (102)

Your sssd must have at least one quotation mark in it, corrupting your directly built query sentence.