# Passing properly formatted windows pathname to SQL server via PYODBC

Tags: python, sql-server, pyodbc

I need python to issue a query via pyodbc to insert a .PNG file into a table as a blob.  The problem seems to have something to do with how the path to the file is represented.  Here's some code:

```
    OutFilePath = 'd:\\DilerBW_images\\'

    OutFileName = SubjID+'_'+str(UserID)+'_'+DateTime+'.png'

    print OutFilePath+OutFileName        
    qstring = ('insert into [wpic-smir].[Diler_BW].[Beckwith].[PlotImages](ID, UserID, ImageType, MoodType, ImageIndex, ImageData)'
    'select '+str(SubjID)+' as ID, '+str(UserID)+' as UserID,'
    '1 as ImageType,'
    'NULL as MoodType,'
    'NULL as ImageIndex,'
    '* from OPENROWSET(Bulk \''+OutFilePath+OutFileName+'\', SINGLE_BLOB) as ImageData')
    print qstring

    cursor.execute(qstring)
    conn.commit()
```

`
And here's the output:

```
   d:\DilerBW_images\999123_999123_2015-01-20_14-25-07.013000.png

    insert into [wpic-smir].[Diler_BW].[Beckwith].[PlotImages](ID, UserID, ImageType, MoodType, ImageIndex, ImageData)select 999123 as ID, 999123 as UserID,1 as ImageType,NULL as MoodType,NULL as ImageIndex,* from OPENROWSET(Bulk 'd:\DilerBW_images\999123_999123_2015-01-20_14-25-07.013000.png', SINGLE_BLOB) as ImageData
```

Now, here's the error I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\pythonscripts\DilerBW_Plot_Single_report_2_EH.py", line 253, in <module>
cursor.execute(qstring)
pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', '[42000] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Cannot bulk load because the file "d:\\DilerBW_images\\999123_999123_2015-01-20_14-25-07.013000.png" could not be opened. Operating system error code 3(The system cannot find the path specified.). (4861) (SQLExecDirectW)')
```

Sorry this is so long.  Notice that the file path in the error message includes double backslashes, where the query only includes singles.  I have looked extensively at the various methods to build the string (os.path.sep, using a raw string, os.path.join), but it doesn't seem to matter, and I'm not certain the input string is the problem.  Again, if I cut and paste the query as it's presented in the output into SSMS and execute it, it works fine.

Thanx.

Comment: Take a look at my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11847994/366335) for inserting blob data without the use of `OPENROWSET`.

Comment: While I'd still like to see someone address the double-backslash issue I'm having, Bryan's "workaround" worked just fine.  Thanx!!