# Firebird database BLOB type with 20,000 bytes, which SQL Server data type to store blob?

Tags: sql-server, blob, firebird, sqldatatypes, firebird-3.0

Migrating data from a Firebird database to SQL Server. There is a BLOB Binary field which has values around 20,000 bytes which was measured using OCTET_LENGTH function.

Which SQL Server data type will house more than 8000 bytes?

Comment: Um, check out the [reference docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-types-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)?

Comment: I did however varbinary seems to max out at 8000, there is image but the docs advise against using them.

Comment: From the docs "varbinary [ ( n | max) ] Variable-length binary data. n can be a value from 1 through 8,000. max indicates that the maximum storage size is 2^31-1 bytes" note **max**.

Comment: So when creating the table in sql server, i put in the keyword max?

Comment: Varbinary(MAX).

Comment: funny thing, this Microsoft datatype was already mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63642220/

Comment: "I did however varbinary seems to max out at 8000" - no, this is a reading error. I suggest reading the docs again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closest equivalent to a Firebird `BLOB SUB_TYPE BINARY` (or `BLOB SUB_TYPE 0` or `BLOB` without explicit subtype), is a `VARBINARY(MAX)`. See [binary and varbinary (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/binary-and-varbinary-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15):

> `varbinary [ ( n | max) ]` Variable-length binary data. `n` can be a
> value from 1 through 8,000. `max` indicates that the maximum storage
> size is 2^31-1 bytes. The storage size is the actual length of the
> data entered + 2 bytes. The data that is entered can be 0 bytes in
> length. The ANSI SQL synonym for `varbinary` is `binary varying`.

There are some differences in how values of these types are accessed (depending on the API used). In Firebird `BLOB` values are stored off-row and are accessed separately (though some APIs will hide this from you), while - IIRC - in SQL Server, `VARBINARY` values are stored on-row and APIs will allow you to access the value directly.