# Type error writing to file in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, urllib

I am writing a Python script to notify me when changes are made to a webpage and store the current state of the page to a file in order to resume seamlessly after rebooting.
The code is as follows:

```
import urllib
url="http://example.com"
filepath="/path/to/file.txt"
try:
    html=open(filepath,"r").read() # Restores imported code from previous session
except:
    html="" # Blanks variable on first run of the script
while True:
    imported=urllib.urlopen(url)
    if imported!=html:
    # Alert me
    html=imported
    open(filepath,"w").write(html)
# Time delay before next iteration
```

Running the script returns:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "April_Fools.py", line 20, in <module>
    open(filepath,"w").write(html)
TypeError: expected a character buffer object

------------------
(program exited with code: 1)
Press return to continue
```

I've no idea what this means. I'm relatively new to Python. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`urllib.urlopen` does not return a string, it returns a response as a file-like object. You need to *read* that response:

```
html = imported.read()
```

Only *then* is `html` a string you can write to a file.

Answer (score 1):

As an aside, using `open(filename).read()` is [not considered good style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373660/file-open-is-this-bad-python-style), because you never close the file. The same goes for writing. Try using a [context manager](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#context-managers) instead:

```
try:
    with open(filepath,"r") as htmlfile:
        html = htmlfile.read()
except:
    html=""
```

The `with` block will automatically close the file when you leave the block.

Comment: upvoting you just because your link made me discover memoryview, which I needed bad. thanks!