# Python csv read file, what if I don't close the file?

Tags: python, csv

I use the following code to read a csv file

```
f = csv.reader(open(filename, 'rb'))
```

Then there's no way I can close `filename`, right? Is there any harm of doing so or is there a better way of reading it?

Comment: Yes, there is some harm: your file can be kept open, so spending system resources and maybe locking this file from access.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is, use [context managers](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#context-managers):

```
with open(filename, 'rb') as handle: 
    f = csv.reader(handle)
```

In general an open unused file descriptor is a resource leak and should be avoided.

---

Interestingly in the case of files, at least the file descriptor is released, as soon as there is no reference to the file any more (see also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1373672/89391)):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import gc
import os
import subprocess

# GC thresholds (http://docs.python.org/3/library/gc.html#gc.set_threshold)
print "Garbage collection thresholds: {}".format(gc.get_threshold())

if __name__ == '__main__':

    pid = os.getpid()

    print('------- No file descriptor ...')    
    subprocess.call(['lsof -p %s' % pid], shell=True)

    x = open('/tmp/test', 'w')
    print('------- Reference to a file ...')
    subprocess.call(['lsof -p %s' % pid], shell=True)

    x = 2
    print('------- FD is freed automatically w/o GC')
    subprocess.call(['lsof -p %s' % pid], shell=True)
```